# Knowing ressources taken by libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I've made a game using libgdx. When I launch it, it takes ~30 Mo of RAM. But the memory taken in RAM keep expanding with time, whereas all of the textures are loaded.

Is there a way to know the ressources used by libgdx?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Start the `jvisualvm.exe` from your java sdk and connect to your running application. (`Program/java/jdk_x_x/bin`) It does show you the real RAM usage and the created classes and so on (See the `Monitor` tab).

Moreover you can profile with it to check if there are performance issues. It also can track the RAM usage. Check out the `sampler` tab for profiling. Simply start the sampler play a bit and shut down the game. After that it asks if you like to have a snapshot of the current status. Or just stop sampling and check the data. Take it and check than which of your stuff does take the most RAM and so on.

Else go for logging your Assetloading and check if you meight make misstakes.

Comment: Thank you ! But it's the java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU who takes 50% of the RAM, and the java.land.Object[] 25%. How to deal with it?

Comment: I think that the floatbuffer is the buffer for rendering so you cant change it. And sure the java lang object[] should be your object arrays so you just could decrease it by using less objects. I wouldnt care about 30MB RAM usage of the VM. If its 30-50MB real usage (not VM usage) i would care.... Now a days it isnt much ram i think. Even for smartphones. Well if it increases you have a leak of disposing data or you have a `new` call inside of your rendering. Take a look at everything inside of your render and delete every new inside of there! It causes alot of troubles lateron.